# Looping within linear programming

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to do some network programming around optimization. Here is a reduced sample:

```
f = Minimize[{q,


  a + b <= q
&& c + d <= q                  // These represent edges in a network
&& c <= q
&& a + b + c + d <= q 
&& a + b + d <= q

&& a + b >= 1                 // other restraints
&& c + d >= 1

&& 0 <= a <= 1
&& 0 <= b <= 1
&& 0 <= c <= 1
&& 0 <= d <= 1

&& 0 <= q <= 4}, { q, a, b, c, d}]
```

While I have answers and know what I'm doing. My question is I wish to speed things up. I wish to change this code from that to this:

```
f = Minimize[{q,


  a + b <= iq
&& c + d <= iq
&& c <= iq
&& a + b + c + d <= iq 
&& a + b + d <= iq

&& a + b >= 1
&& c + d >= 1

&& 0 <= a <= 1
&& 0 <= b <= 1
&& 0 <= c <= 1
&& 0 <= d <= 1

&& 0 <= q <= (i*4)}, { q, a, b, c, d}]
```

where "i" will be an incrementing number.

I've been reading Stephen Wolfram's Mathematica second edition (1991?) book which I loaned from my university library, whilst it's been a major help in guiding me this far. It is a little outdated and searching the internet has provided little help either. I'm working with Mathematica 8.0.0.0.

I'm taking a guess that each line with i*q cannot have the same i as this would prove difficult in linear optimization(?)... Please correct me if I'm wrong

I'm a beginner to Mathematica and I'm finding the language to be much more easier to understand that Matlab. I have the answers I want or know how to get the remaining answers. I just want to speed things up.

Many thanks in helping me become more efficient in this program

**EDIT::**

Hi, thanks for the feedback.

**@David:** This isn't the full constraint table. I've reduced it down so some are missing. I apologise for missing constraints.

**@Jinxed:** Basically I'm trying to figure out q for incrementing values of i. So in a loop:

```
 a + b <= iq
 && c + d <= iq
 && c <= iq
 && a + b + c + d <= iq 
 && a + b + d <= iq
```

becomes =>

```
 a + b <= 2q
 && c + d <= 2iq
 && c <= 2iq
 && a + b + c + d <= 1q 
 && a + b + d <= 2iq
```

Then =>

```
 a + b <= 3q
 && c + d <= 3q
 && c <= 3q
 && a + b + c + d <= 1q 
 && a + b + d <= 3q
```

up until "i" reaches a top. I'm trying to observe what happens when I bottleneck particular edges in a network and the effects of it.

As I've said before, I'm a total beginner on this program so please forgive me if there are obvious fallings in places.

Comment: If speed is what you are looking for then there is the built-in LinearProgramming function which provides access to lots of the classical linear programming algorithms and should be faster and easier to use than crafting a manual Minimize. Look it up in the documentation or Google for it.

Comment: Are there any constraints on your variables (such as all non-negative)?  You have $c+d \leq q$ and $c \leq q$ when only one is needed (assuming non-negative variables).  Simplify your constraints first.  Also, is $iq$ a separate variable?

Comment: Are you aware of the 1000's of pages of built-in documentation? A massive resource of Mathematica information can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice).

Comment: `iq` looks like a typo: Did you mean `i*q`? What is it exactly, that you want to speed up? If it is execution speed, look at Bill's comment. If it is your speed in working with *Mathematica* , look at Sjoerd's.

Comment: Hi, please see edit in original post. I'm trying to speed up the results yield from having to change each value then run to just having a script run each value and output the everything I need.

Comment: This question would be *much* clearer if you posted the code that actually takes too much time. I've tried your first two code blocks, and neither takes more than a few milliseconds. Without that, the only tip that comes to mind is use `FindMinimum` instead of `Minimize`. `Minimize` tries to solve the problem symbolically, which is in general more expensive. `FindMinimum` uses local optimization, which is usually fastest, and for an LP is guaranteed to find the global minimum.

Comment: Also, `//` does not start a comment in Mathematica code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

```
{"For i= " ~~ ToString[#] , Minimize[{q, 
 a + b <= # q && c + d <= # q && c <= # q && 
  a + b + c + d <= # q && a + b + d <= # q && a + b >= 1 && 
  c + d >= 1 && 0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1 && 
  0 <= d <= 1 && 0 <= q <= 4}, {q, a, b, c, d}]} & /@ Range[8]
```

Gives:

[image]